# Mouseover function not creating pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the cursor hovers over my link, I want it to display a message saying "Hovering". I have tried the code below, but it does not create this window. Why not?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" id="home_button">
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $("#menu ul li a").mouseover(function()
    {
      alert("Hovering");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, you just need to fix your HTML tags.

You are missing the anchor and list-item closure tags.

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" id="home_button">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/40acxxet/1/

Comment: My mistake, this is correct, please highlight it is the missings `<a>` closure and content.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I realised that the problem is how I told my code where to find the jquery library. I was using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`. But changing it to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` seems to have fixed it.